# Background colour in Pandas - Shown Black instead of different colours

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am playing with colours in pandas:

```
def apply_colour1(data):
    #colour = ['background-color: aquamarine', 'background-color: lightseagreen']
    colour = ['background-color: Green', 'background-color: Blue']
    return_data = []
    colour_index = 0
    prev_val = True
    for i in data.iteritems():
        if i[1]:
            return_data.append('background-color: '+colour[colour_index])
            prev_val = True
        else:
            if prev_val:
                if colour_index:
                    colour_index = 0
                else:
                    colour_index = 1
            return_data.append('')
            prev_val = False
    
    print(return_data)
    return return_data

df = pd.concat([df1,df2], ignore_index=True, axis=0)
df = df.style.apply(apply_colour1, axis=0)
```

I just want to change the background colour[Green] of the columns where the text is available, and if there is empty column, then change the colour [Blue] and so on.

I did not get any errors, but when I opened the excel in LiberOffice Calc in Ubuntu, I got the excel sheet like this:

[image: output_screen_shot]

The Black colour is shown instead of Green/Blue colours. How can I solve this?

Comment: Change this `return_data.append('background-color: '+colour[colour_index])` to `return_data.append(colour[colour_index])` or leave only color names in the `color` list

Comment: @Vitalizzare, thanks for pointing it out, now I got why it is not worked